# Project wont start after adding hibernate-core and spring-orm to maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, pom.xml

I just added:

```
  <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

to my project and it caused some problems. Simpley my project won't run. Before adding these libraries everything wotked fine.

Those are my server logs:

> sie 28, 2016 2:07:41 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class sie 28, 2016 2:07:44 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute INFO: At least one JAR
>   was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for
>   this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs
>   were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. sie 28, 2016 2:07:44 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   initWebApplicationContext INFO: Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization started sie 28, 2016 2:07:44 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup
>   date [Sun Aug 28 14:07:44 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy sie
>   28, 2016 2:07:44 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class
>   com.packt.webstore.configuration.WebConfiguration] sie 28, 2016
>   2:07:46 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
>    INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and
>   supported for autowiring sie 28, 2016 2:07:46 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   initWebApplicationContext SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$FieldCallback;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:418)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:908)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:628)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:470)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5066)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> sie 28, 2016 2:07:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full
>   details will be found in the appropriate container log file sie 28,
>   2016 2:07:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors sie 28, 2016
>   2:07:46 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   doClose INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun
>   Aug 28 14:07:44 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy sie 28, 2016
>   2:07:46 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   doClose WARNING: Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling
>   ContextClosedEvent java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before
>   multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext:
>   startup date [Sun Aug 28 14:07:44 CEST 2016]; root of context
>   hierarchy     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> sie 28, 2016 2:07:46 PM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>   doClose WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context
>   close java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not
>   initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the
>   context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Aug 28 14:07:44
>   CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> [2016-08-28 02:07:46,137] Artifact webstore:war: Error during artifact
>   deployment. See server log for details. sie 28, 2016 2:07:50 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying
>   web application directory
>   C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\manager
>   sie 28, 2016 2:07:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployDirectory INFO: Deployment of web application directory
>   C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\manager
>   has finished in 166 ms

This is my `pom.xml file`:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
  <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.39</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <!--spring security-->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <!--end of spring security-->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: You're using different versions of spring-framework jars: 4.0.3 and 4.3.0. Don't.

Comment: @JBNizet I changed it but It didn't help

Comment: Can you try mvn dependency:tree and post what you get here. Most likely that it is a conflict or mismatch version issue

Comment: I solved the problem. You are right guys. So far works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to align the version of all spring related dependancy

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
  <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.39</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <!--spring security-->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <!--end of spring security-->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```